# how to solve this mixed content font issue?

Tags: javascript, php, css, https, twitter-oauth

I get following error when I log into my site through Twitter api.

> Mixed Content: The page at "https://www.example.com/page/" was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font "http://myntra.myntassets.com/skin2/fonts/1D41FF_1_0.woff". This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can I solve this mixed content font issue?

Comment: remove http: and try once .Means `//myntra.myntassets.com/skin2/fonts/1D41FF_1_0.woff`

Answer (score 0):

Because your main page is loading over `HTTPS`, you are getting an error because the font you are trying to load is using plain old `HTTP`, which is where the mixed-content issue is coming from. You can simply remove the `http:` from the domain, and just start it with `//`.

**Example**

`//myntra.myntassets.com/skin2/fonts/1D41FF_1_0.woff`

That is treated just like a normal link, but you aren't explicitly declaring `HTTP` or `HTTPS`.